# IGNORECASE errors in Python's re.Scanner?

Tags: python, regex, case-insensitive

There is hidden but well known [functionality](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/457664-hidden-scanner-functionality-in-re-module/) in re module

```
import re

def s_ident(scanner, token): return token
def s_operator(scanner, token): return "op%s" % token
def s_float(scanner, token): return float(token)
def s_int(scanner, token): return int(token)

scanner = re.Scanner([
    (r"[a-zA-Z]\w*", s_ident),
    (r"\d+\.\d*", s_float),
    (r"\d+", s_int),
    (r"=|\+|-|\*|/", s_operator),
    (r"\s+", None),
    ])

print scanner.scan("Sum = 3*foo + 312.50 + bar")
# (['Sum', 'op=', 3, 'op*', 'foo', 'op+', 312.5, 'op+', 'bar'], '')
```

I want to use IGNORECASE flag here but it seems it does not work:

```
import re

def s_ident(scanner, token): return token
def s_operator(scanner, token): return "op%s" % token
def s_float(scanner, token): return float(token)
def s_int(scanner, token): return int(token)

scanner = re.Scanner([
    (r"(?i)[a-z]\w*", s_ident),
    (r"\d+\.\d*", s_float),
    (r"\d+", s_int),
    (r"=|\+|-|\*|/", s_operator),
    (r"\s+", None),
    ])

print scanner.scan("Sum = 3*foo + 312.50 + bar")
# ([], 'Sum = 3*foo + 312.50 + bar')
```

Is it a issue of the Scanner or error in my code?
Is it possible to implement non-case-sensitive matching using Scanner?

This issue was initially reproduced on Python 2.7.9.

Expected value:
(['Sum', 'op=', 3, 'op*', 'foo', 'op+', 312.5, 'op+', 'bar'], '')

Actual value:
([], 'Sum = 3*foo + 312.50 + bar')

Comment: Is this part of the python standard library? If not, the lib should be identified and put into tags

Comment: I can't reproduce that here using Python 2.7.10 (Anaconda/Windows 64 bit). @progo: Yes, it's in the standard library, but undocumented.

Comment: @TimPietzcker You can not reproduce my case or using of Scanner?

Comment: Works [in 2.7.10](http://ideone.com/t3vaBw)

Comment: I copied your exact code into a new Python script, and the second version had the same (correct) output as the first.

Comment: I used Python 2.7.9.

Comment: No repro in Python 2.7.8 [GCC 4.8.3] on cygwin or Python 2.6.6 [GCC 4.4.6 20110731 (Red Hat 4.4.6-3)] on linux2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the `flags` parameter to the constructor.

```
scanner = re.Scanner([
    (r"[a-z]\w*", s_ident),
    (r"\d+\.\d*", s_float),
    (r"\d+", s_int),
    (r"=|\+|-|\*|/", s_operator),
    (r"\s+", None),
    ], flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Source for `Scanner`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/re.py#L345

Comment: Thanks . It works. Checked in Python 2.7.9 and 2.7.10.

Comment: what if u want case to be ignored only for some of the regexes, and for others you need it to be case sensitive ? im guessing the `flags` parameter is applied to all the regexes in the list right?

Comment: @KaustavDatta Yes, the flags applies to all subpatterns. The Scanner compiles all of the subpatterns into a single pattern for faster execution.
Python does not allow specifying flags that only applies to part of a pattern. So it is not possible to do what you want.